# Why does my code create a .txt file, but doesn't write information in it?

Tags: java, file

Pretty self explanatory title. Why is my program not writing text into the .txt file? Here's the code:

```
package juego;  
import java.io.*;
/**
*
* @author Administrador
*/
public class Archivo 
{
    public void crearArchivo()
    {
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ReglasDelTablero.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.println("<7,0> , <0,0>");
        pw.println("<4,1> , <7,2> | <2,7> , <5,5> | <1,2> , <7,4> | <0,4> , <2,5>");
        pw.println("<7,7> , <3,6> | <6,4> , <3,5> | <4,0> , <2,1> | <2,4> , <0,3>");
    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printwriter not writing to outputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088219/printwriter-not-writing-to-outputstream)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to close the writers so the changes show up in the text file. The `finally` block ensures that this happens even when an error occurs.

```
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ReglasDelTablero.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    //...
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
} finally {
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
}
```

Alternatively you could also use a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which will automatically close the writers:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ReglasDelTablero.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);)
{
    //...
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package juego;  
import java.io.*;
/**
*
* @author Administrador
*/
public class Archivo 
{
    public void crearArchivo()
    {
      PrintWriter pw = null;
    try
    {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("ReglasDelTablero.txt"));//onle line chain


        pw.println("<7,0> , <0,0>");
        pw.println("<4,1> , <7,2> | <2,7> , <5,5> | <1,2> , <7,4> | <0,4> , <2,5>");
        pw.println("<7,7> , <3,6> | <6,4> , <3,5> | <4,0> , <2,1> | <2,4> , <0,3>");
    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }finally{

         if(pw!=null){
                try{ pw.close();...catch
         }

   }
```

try-catch rsources is fine for some cases but this is the old way and works better when you have more than 1 exception in a block

Comment: What makes you think this works better if there's more than one exception? You can catch more than one exception in a try-with-resources block...

Comment: If you need to get a Connection object from a pool that can throw an exception, then a statement and a recordset from that ... then depending on an if call fn1 with the db result or fn2 ...

Comment: I don't see how any of that is a reason not to use try - with - resources.